# Error when rendering a Alloy UI form in Liferay

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

This is a form in my Liferay portlet.

```
<aui:form method="post" action="<%=loginURL%>">
    <aui:fieldset>      
        <aui:input name="userName" label="Usernam">
            <aui:validator name="required">             
            </aui:validator>
        </aui:input>    
        <aui:input name="password" label="Password" type="password"></aui:input>
        <aui:button type="submit" value="Login"></aui:button>
    </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

When I deploy the portlet and go to the page that contains this form I get this error:

> The aui:validator tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface.

I don't understand the problem. How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the problem.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13651436/468763) will help you understand the problem in detail, though the answer is for spring tag still it applies to all custom tags created for JSP.

> How can I fix it?

You can fix it by referencing the correct updated jar (`util-taglib.jar`) & including the correct TLD (`aui.tld`) inside `WEB-INF/tld/` for your custom portlet.