# The form:hidden tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required inter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring3 and hibernate to develop this simple form:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addClass" commandName="trainingclass">
    <form:hidden path="id" />
```

and the corresponding command:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TrainingClass")
public class TrainingClass {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
   // @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    ....
}
```

I am getting the exception in the title. I tried to use some transient property such as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TrainingClass")
public class TrainingClass {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
   // @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private Integer dim;
}

<form:form method="post" action="addClass" commandName="trainingclass">
        <form:hidden path="dim" />
```

Still the exception is there.

Then I tried:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addClass" commandName="trainingclass">
            <form:hidden path="dim" value="dummy"/>
```

Still the same problem.

I searched google and everywhere it seemed to be using  without any issues.

The exception trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/trainingClassForm.jsp (line: 13, column: 2) The form:hidden tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:149)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:832)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:895)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1817)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: see already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648357/the-formform-tag-declares-that-it-accepts-dynamic-attributes-but-does-not-imple)